# IIS ARR and SharePoint 2013

Tags: iis, sharepoint, arr

I am trying to access SharePoint 2013 over the internet using an IIS ARR for rewriting and SSL offloading.

Currently, when I access SharePoint via my internal network using the following URL

```
http://shareserver
```

Which works perfectly.  However, when I attempt to access it externally, I get a message that simply says "401 UNAUTHORIZED".

Here are my current settings:

In IIS ARR, it is a simple rewrite at the server level (i.e. no farm) that rewrites

```
https://remote.domain.com to http://shareserver
```

In SharePoint, I have Alternative Access Mappings as follows:

```
Internal URL: http://shareserver
Zone: Default
Public URL: http://shareserver

Internal URL: https://remote.domain.com
Zone: Internet
Public URL: https://remote.domain.com
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need IIS rewrite for this?

I suppose whenever you want to separate address for internal and internet, you just extend your web application to internet zone with that address, that's all!
SharePoint will do the address translation, no need to use URL rewriter.
Hope this helps.

Edit:
Here's a good explanation of Alternate Access Mappings. I still think that you don't need to use URL rewrite, since AAM is suffice.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx

Comment: I need IIS Rewrite because I only have a single external IP so I use IIS as a reverse proxy to deliver multiple sites based on the URL requested -